# Pass Input value to java file in ATG

Tags: java, html, jsp, atg

I'm new for atg and I have input field in my .jsp file as below..

```
    <input type="email"  id="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control">
```

I want to pass value in this field, to my java file. I don't know hoe to do that.
Can anyone help me please.

Comment: I am voting to have this question closed as it is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set a field in a FormHandler, you should use dsp tag library  [dsp:input](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/PageDevGuide/html/s1218dspinput01.html) and it should be inside of `form` tag  [dsp:form](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/PageDevGuide/html/s1210dspform01.html). In that way you'll have fields populated by atg on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The way ATG works for form binding (the process of attaching a value from an HTML form field to a value in a Java component) is to use the DSP form tags along with a formhandler.

Create a java class as a bean with a property called, say, `email`. I.e. with a `getEmail` and `setEmail` method (this is standard Java, look up how to define a JavaBean in Java).

Create a request-scoped named Nucleus component as an instance of this class (refer to the Programming Guide in the ATG documentation, specifically the section called *Nucleus: Organizing JavaBean Components*)

Then in your JSP page use the `dsp:input` tag to bind to your bean property (refer to the *Forms* section in the ATG Page Developers guide).

You will also need to implement a submit handler method for your form (refer to the section *Working with Forms and Form Handlers* in the ATG Programming Guide).

Answer (score -1):

Create a ATG component(Java file and properties file). Keep two properties in it named `firstName` and `lastName` and a handler method named `handleSubmitForm`.
Now add this content in your jsp:

```
<dsp:page>
<dsp:body>
<dsp:form>
<dsp:input name="studentName" type="test" bean="MyFormHandler.firstName"/>
<dsp:input name="studentName" type="test" bean="MyFormHandler.lastName"/>
<dsp:input name="submit" value="Submit" bean="MyFormHandler.submitForm"/>
</dsp:form>
</dsp:body>
</dsp:page>
```

Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0602formhandlersandhandlermethods01.html) for more explanation.

Comment: `<dsp:page>
<dsp:body>
<dsp:form>
<dsp:input name="Email" type="test" bean="MyFormHandler.email"/>
<dsp:input name="submit" value="Submit" bean="MyFormHandler.submitForm"/>
</dsp:form>
</dsp:body>
</dsp:page>`